# What is the output of this VCO?

Tags: output, pll, vco

I am using [ROS-43-119+](https://www.minicircuits.com/pdfs/ROS-43-119+.pdf) from Mini-circuits. I need a VCO that can generate a 40MHz frequency.
[ROS-43-119+](https://www.minicircuits.com/pdfs/ROS-43-119+.pdf) can generate my required frequency by controlling the tuning voltage.

I need sinewave output from the VCO. There is no mention of the output type in the datasheet.

So what is the out type of this VCO?

Comment: The harmonic spec gives a hint - its not a square wave.

Comment: The other hint @Kartman -18 dBc typ  -10 dBc max , it's not a sine wave either , it's in between

Comment: you can improve square wave with a filter. PLs spec SNR of sine wave in dB or harmonics

Comment: Maybe if you told us what the VCO is driving then we could advise on suitabiliy,  possible implementations of filtering if needed, or indeed other options.

Comment: @Tesla23 The VCO is controlled by ADF4106 for generating a 40MHz signal. The output from the VCO is fed to clock buffers and then fed back into ADF4106 as Reference In

Comment: If you are feeding it to clock buffers then you probably aren't worried about starting with a pure sinusoid. The VCO may well be fine as it is. If it is essential that you get a 50% duty cycle, then either some filtering on the output of the VCO should get you pretty close, if 50% is essential consider generating 80MHz and dividing by 2.

Comment: @Tesla23 the output of the VCO is "clipped sine wave" by any chance?

Comment: It will be a distorted sine wave - has some 2nd, little 3rd.  Clipped sine would be the opposite.  Also, be careful with your PLL as the tuning voltage is 0.5V for 40MHz, could give trouble with passive loop filters - check charge pump output voltage swing. If active filter, check op amp can drive down to near 0V.

Answer (score 0):

The output from the harmonic table vs f specs appears simply as a slew rate limited or low pass filtered square wave with some asymmetry and 2f harmonic at **-18 dBc typ, -10 dBc max.**  i.e. **SNR = 10 dB**

This will improve Sine SNR greatly by almost 40 dB to about **55 dB SNR** on voltage ratio due to 2f & 3f attenuation 80,120  MHz, but it depends, what you need.  The 50 Ohm load attenuates -6dB with source.

[image]

Alternatively for 60 dB SNR

[image]